# From VS2013 to VS2017 std::async does not start a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I updated my Visual Studio from 2013 to 2017. 
Compiling was fine but it seems like that the std::async call didn't open a new thread. (I cant see a new one in the thread-window while debugging. Also it looks like the thread which calls the the async function does the job...)

That is my function call:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```

I didn't change anything in my code and in VS2013 was everything working fine.

Any Idea? Google can't tell me a lot about this but maybe i have the wrong keywords. So keywords would also help!

Thank you

Comment: Are you testing in Release or Debug build?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Debug

Comment: If you place a break point in `myfunction` you will see that it is running in a worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple Solution:

```
std::thread t(myfunction, this);
t.detach();
```

Answer (score 9):

In VS2013, `std::async` does not obey the C++ standard.

There was a disagreement, and the developers working on MSVC wanted `std::async`'s `std::future` to behave like every other `std::future`.

The standard disagreed.

They released a non-standard compliant `std::future` in 2013.  In 2015 if I remember correctly, they started following the standard.

The standard states that the destructor of the `std::future` owning the shared state generated by `std::async( std::launch::async` blocks until the task is complete.

This is because, in practice, dangling threads are bad for programs behaving in a predictable manner.

You are now in charge of owning and persisting the `future` returned from

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```

and `f.wait` or `f.get`ing it when you need it to be ready.

This may require changing how your code works; for example, keeping a vector of futures around (if you have more than one), or adding a `std::future<?>` member to `this` and storing it (this also ensures that the async call doesn't outlive the object lifetime!).

---

As a second note, `std::async` on windows also uses a bounded thread pool; if there are more than a certain number of `async` tasks active, new tasks may not be launched.

They have plans to fix it (as it goes against the advice in the standard), but at this point I would still recommend using `std::thread`, and if you need `std::async` like behavior implementing something similar yourself.

My personal tendency is to create problem-specific `thread_pool`s that own a certain number of `std::thread`s, but let you queue tasks and get `future`s (with custom extensions that give me very limited continuation capabilities) back from it.

This makes the thread ownership and dependencies more explicit, and avoids dealing with the MSVC non-standard compliant quirks that still exist.

Comment: This is a superior answer, which not only explains what needs to be done, and in more detail, but also *why*. The relative dearth of upvotes is perplexing to me.

Answer (score 7):

You need to hold on to the `std::future` returned by `async` otherwise the destructor of the temporary will block until the work is finished.

```
auto t = std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```

Comment: You mean std::future?

Comment: Try examining or dumping `std::this_thread::get_id()` in the main code and the asynchronous code to see what is really happening.

Comment: Sounds good but also not working for me.
Did i have to declare the auto t variable in a header? maybe the compiler optimized it out because i doing nothing with it? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like std::async is whaiting for return to end. So, if you symply call it, doesn't work asynchronous.

```
std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```

The Key is define an answer: myfunction must to return std::future and you need to define and same type to response.

```
std::future<int> foo = std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```

In case you call std::async inside a constructor, foo must be member of the class.

```
class MyClass {
    //Your code
    private:
        std::future<int> exitThread;
}
```

And, when you call std::async must be

```
exitThread = std::async(std::launch::async, myfunction, this);
```